# IONIC - get multiple checkbox status as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

My checkbox code:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Beverage Size</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Small</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="drinkSmall" color="blue" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Regular</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="drinkRegular" color="blue" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Large</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="drinkLarge" color="blue" checked="true"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
```

My submit button:

```
    <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="addBeverage(
      drinkName,
      drinkmenuDesc,
      drinkPrice,
      drinkCategory,
      drinkSmall,
      drinkRegular,
      drinkLarge
    )" [disabled]="!menuName">
            Add Beverage
          </button>
```

Edited:
I want to pass all the checkbox status as a parameter of a function. The drinkSmall, drinkRegular, drinkLarge should be the status of checkbox.

Comment: what is menuName?

Comment: are you solve this...Erex give good answer. You are any Requirement....

Comment: yup, it solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a object that holds the checkbox values. Then you can pass that object to your submit function. See below for a example using a model called "checkboxes"

**TS:**

```
// A achecboxes object in your controller:
    checkboxes: any = {
       drinkSmall: true,
       drinkRegular: true,
       drinkLarge: true
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Beverage Size</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Small</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxes.drinkSmall" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Regular</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxes.drinkRegular" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Large</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkboxes.drinkLarge" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="addBeverage(checkboxes)" [disabled]="!menuName">
            Add Beverage
    </button>
```

Comment: if i have multiple parameter to pass in the function so i will just make it like: addBeverage(para1,para2,para3,checkboxes) ?

Comment: futhermore, if the checkbox being checked or unchecked, the object in the checkboxes will auto flag to true/false as well?

Comment: @Jerry Yes to both your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

In .ts you need to create an **object**.

```
  checkboxes: any = {
    drinkSmall: true,
    drinkRegular: true,
    drinkLarge: true
  };

  data: any = {
    checkboxes:this.checkboxes,
    para1:'',
    para2:'',
    para3:''
  };
```

**In `.html` you need to change like**

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Beverage Size</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Small</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.checkboxes.drinkSmall" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Regular</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.checkboxes.drinkRegular" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Large</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="data.checkboxes.drinkLarge" color="blue"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>

  <button ion-button color="primary" block (click)="addBeverage(data)" [disabled]="!menuName">
    Add Beverage
  </button>
```

Here one object data holds multiple `checkbox` as well as `para1,para2,para3`

**Output of `console.log`**

[image: output]